# EclipseLink Core 2.5.2 missing Import-Package javax.xml.bind

Tags: osgi, eclipselink, moxy

The EclipseLink bundle (org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.5.2) is missing the import statement `javax.xml.bind` in its header entry of `Import-Package`. I get the same error described here:
[Glassfish 4 moxy eclipselink 2.5.2 oxm object graph troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350705/glassfish-4-moxy-eclipselink-2-5-2-oxm-object-graph-troubles)

I add to declare `javax.xml.bind` as bootdelegated in OSGi, otherwise EclipseLink MOXy is not working properly.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Did you report a bug to the EclipseLink project?

Comment: Just done it... The bug report can be found here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this bug in EclipseLink 2.5.3.
Also, EclipseLink 2.6.0 does not contain this issue.

Thanks for creating the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix missing import with fragment bundles, see http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment

If the host bundle has the following in its manifest:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.core
Bundle-Version: 2.5.2
```

then your fragment manifest should have:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.core.myfragment
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.persistence.core; bundle-version="2.5.2"
Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
```

Comment: That sounds interesting... I will try this workaround.

Comment: When I was working on an osgi project, i always created an empty maven project which just created the empty jar but with the manifest. It was the easiest way to integrate the libary-fixes to the build lifecycle. The eclipse virgo bundlor and a template.mf will be big help.